# How to update column and Set value with count from other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table with column id, name, money, count_greater

```
id    name    money    count_greater
-------------------------------------
1     John    100      3
2     Tommy   200      2
3     Alex    300      1
4     Wink    400      0
```

Count_greater is the column which **find from other rows and count number of people have money larger than current people**.

What is mysql query to do this ?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I would not recommend storing a value that is going to be that fluid and dynamic in a column. This is best derived in a stored procedure or view as needed.

Comment: *find from other rows and count number of people have money larger than current people* who are current people ? what to count ? how to count ? where to count ?

Comment: @jWeaver presumably OP means count the number of rows in which the money column is greater than that of the selected row. I.e. Alex gets updated with pseudo `count rows where money > 400` = 1 -> `update table set count_greater = 1 where id = 3` but do all of the rows at once, not just Alex.

Comment: I'm going to side with @JoeStefanelli on this, calculated values are better off not stored in the database, as they would need to change after each and every update. This is something you can query for, however. Before we help you do that, it's important to know what you want to do in case of a tie?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is :

```
Select ID,name,money
        ,(select COUNT(*) from #temp t2 where t2.money > t1.money) 'count_greater'
from #temp t1
```